# can Python Tkinter widget show a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, vpython

Is there a widget that shows a thread visually for Tkinter?

reason why. I want to open a Vpython window inside a Tkinter window.
I know there is a possibility to open a Vpython thread on the side while Tkinter is active, but can i show it inside Tkinter? (Like in some sort of Frame)

Comment: No, but it's possible to write your own custom REPL by writing a custom subclass of [`cmd`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/cmd.html). Batteries not included, some assembly required ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no widget to do that.